# AJAX loaded content with lightbox2

Tags: javascript, ajax, lightbox2

I'm using the [Lightbox2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) script and the content of my page is loaded via an AJAX request.
I don't find any function to attach new images or initialize Lightbox2 after an AJAX request, How can I make that in order to use Lightbox2 for images loaded via AJAX ?

Léo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation files: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
You do not need to initiate anything, any image link with the `data-lightbox` attribute like this:

```
<a href="img/image-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption">Image #1</a>
```

will work automagically even if loaded by AJAX as soon as you add it to your DOM.

**EDIT:** After having taken a look at the lightbox script, you may have to change as well the line #51:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(event) {
```

into this:

```
$('body').live('click', 'a[rel^=lightbox], area[rel^=lightbox], a[data-lightbox], area[data-lightbox]', function(event) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I just made a stupid mistake, and the original code is working.

Answer (score 9):

I had to reinitialize lightbox in order to detect new images. I have done that like this:

```
window.lightbox.init();
```

I placed this code in my success handler of ajax call after I have added the new content:

```
contentContainer.empty().html(data);
```